# Adding text to a paragraph using .val()

Tags: jquery, input

I am trying to change the text inside a paragraph whenever a submit button is clicked.
For some reason it doesn't work. I tried finding answers in other questions but couldn't.
Why isn't this working??
Javascript code:

```
var $submit = $('input:submit');
$submit.click(function(){
    var $newText = $('input:text').val();
    var $p = $('#newStatus');
    $p.text($newText);
});
```

Html:

```
<div class = "grid_12">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="status">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value = "Post">
  </form>
  <p id = "newStatus"></p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

That's because the form is submitted, prevent the default action of the event:

```
$submit.click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var $submit = $('input:submit');
$submit.click(function(){
    var $newText = $('input:text').val();
    var $p = $('#newStatus');
    $p.text($newText);
    return false;   // prevent form from being submitted
});
```

Actually your forms gets submitted, so we need to stop that.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3wAQP/)